# Ref command does not work in pseudocode

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithmicx

I want to use \ref command in my pseudocode like this:
1st Line : "mut Eq. x"
2nd Line :"cr Eq. y"
3rd Line :"sel Eq. z"
But i am getting "Latex Error : Command \item invalid in math mode" in the 2nd Line. 1st Line seems to be working. How can i fix it? Any help appreciated

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\let\textbf\relax}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \If {$\boldsymbol{E_r}$ = $\boldsymbol{M_r}$} \boldsymbol{$let$~$bac$~$ go:$}
            \State \boldsymbol{$ME$~$mut$~$as$~$in$~$(Eq.$~$$} \ref{eq:best1})
            \State \boldsymbol{$ME$~$cr$~$as$~$in$~$(Eq.$~$)$} \ref{eq:creq})
            \State \boldsymbol{$DE$~$sel$~$as$~$in$~$(Eq.$~$)$} \ref{eq:seleq})
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `$\boldsymbol{..}$` rather than `\boldsymbol{$..$}`. Since your main problem seems to use a completely bizarre setup, I don't know how to properly present a solution. Is the `\boldsymbol` really necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your setup:

- `\boldsymbol` should be used in math mode. That is, `$\boldsymbol{..}$` and not `\boldsymbol{$..$}`;
- If you use a construction like `\If{<condition>}`, it needs to be closed later using `\EndIf`;
- `\label`-`\ref` works out-of-the-box inside `algorithmic` (see below).

Here is a simplified example, since I don't know what the use of all the `\boldsymbol` notation is for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \If {$\boldsymbol{E_r}$ = $\boldsymbol{M_r}$}
      \State ME mut as in (Eq.~\ref{eq:label})
    \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eq:label}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\boldsymbol` is obsolete and `\bm` should be used, loading the corresponding package.